# How to start bluetooth pairing process?

Tags: bluetooth, java

I have an Java application on my PC and database.There are some MAC 
and PIN data in DB.

I'm sending messages (now it's text files over OBEX put method, but in 
future it will be SMS messages i hope :) ), so when i discover some 
device, then discover needed service i'm looking to the DB and if the 
phone MAC in the DB i need to start PAIRING with predefined PIN. 
I've coded all the process, except the PAIRING... How to initialize 
it ?

Comment: BlueCove libraries on Linux....

Comment: Do you have an application (j2me) on your mobile, or you´re are sending it directly?

Comment: How did you send the files, i mean directly to the phone, or you have an application (j2me) on it?
How could yo send directly to the native BT, i.e. when you send files directly to mobile.

and for authenticate you must use: javax.obex
Interface Authenticator

Comment: i've used blucove library and OBEX protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register a passkey-agent which inputs the PIN when it is requested. More info [here](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/bluecove-bluez/apidocs/org/bluez/v3/Security.html).